# cleaner way to write this sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

sometimes when I write sql I encounter the following situation:

```
select A = (
               select sum(A)
               --... big query using abc
           ),
select B = (
               select sum(B)
               --... same big query using abc
           )
from abc
```

Maybe it doesn't look very well, but it's the only way I can think of in some situations. So the question is: `big query` is repeated, perhaps there is a cleaner way to write same thing?

**Clarifications:** `abc` is a bunch of joins. `using abc` means using current abc row's data. `big query` is not the same as `abc`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outer apply will help here:

```
   select *
   from abc
    outer apply (
      select sum(a) as sumA, sum(b) as sumB
      -- big query using abc
   ) sums
```

Answer (score 1):

if the 'big query' is the same in all the subselects, can't you just do:

```
select sum(a), sum(b)
from abc
where ...big query
```

Can't be more helpful without a decent set of example data and corresponsing query..

Comment: but a and b columns can't be on the group by clause :P

Comment: @aF: I totally agree with you, but he hasn't said there is a group by clause ;) If there isn't, then its perfectly valid..

Answer (score 0):

your query could be simplified to

```
SELECT sum(a) as A, sum(b) as B
FROM abc
```

although i suspect you've oversimplified your situation

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what to do without seeing actual query and what you are trying to achieve. There are some approaches that might be useful.
1. Use CTE or derived table for your big query
2. In some cases it can be replaced with a number of `SUM(CASE WHEN [condition] THEN field END)`

Answer (score 0):

If A and B are fields, you can just put both `sum`s in the query:

```
select sum(a), sum(b) from abc
```

If what you want to do is to aggregate the same rows depending on different conditions, you can often use `case`. Imagine you have a table `TASKS` with fields `STATUS` and `EFFORT`, and you want to count both `ACTIVE` and `PASSIVE` tasks, and get the total effort of each aggregate. You could do:

```
select
count(case when status = 'ACTIVE' then 1 end) active_nr,
sum(case when status = 'ACTIVE' then effort else 0 end) active_effort,
count(case when status = 'PASSIVE' then 1 end) passive_nr,
sum(case when status = 'PASSIVE' then effort else 0 end) passive_effort
from tasks;
```

This is a simple example, the predicates tested by `case` can be as complex as you need, involving multiple fields, etc. As a bonus, this approach will usually be nicer to the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(A),sum(B)
--... big query using abc
from abc
```

No need to split it up.